# How to interact with IE iframe without iframe id

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I need to click a div inside an iframe in order to trigger a download. I'm having a hard time trying to locate the iframe element as it doesn't have an ID.  Here is the iframe element:

```
<iframe title="data visualization" src="https://sample.com" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; visibility: visible;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And this is the div element inside the iframe:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="tabToolbarButton tab-widget download" role="button" style="width: 95px; -ms-touch-action: none;" aria-label="Download">
    <span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-download"></span>
    <span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Download</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not post code as a screenshot.  Take your code and post it in the question directly so that someone can potentially replicate your issue on their machine.

Comment: Noted, codes added.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of it's attributes. For example,

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='data visualization']").contentDocument.querySelector(".tabToolbarButtonText").click 'change this end bit for the appropriate element to click
```

Perhaps

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='data visualization']").contentDocument.querySelector(".download").click 'change this end bit for the appropriate element to click
```

Or it's `src` attribute value direct:

```
ie.Navigate "https://sample.com"
```

Modern browsers are optimised for [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) so this method is fast. Using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) also stops at first match which is again an efficiency gain here.

Comment: Thanks Qharr, I've tried the code below, however It doesn't work.. 
`If waitElement("iframe", "title", "data visualization", 30) = True Then 

For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
If ele.getAttribute("title") = "data visualization" Then

ele.contentDocument.querySelector("[class='tabToolbarButton tab-widget download']").Click

Exit For
End If
Next ele
Else
MsgBox "fail"
End If`

Comment: I can't use querySelector(".tabToolbarButtonText") as there's a lot of that kind that only differs on innertext.

Comment: You mean that lots of items with the same class that only differ by innerText? No other attributes to differentiate or relationship to another element that uniquely identifies?

Comment: Yes, just like this one which is another buttom within the iframe.. `<div tabindex="-1" class="tabToolbarButton tab-widget share" role="button" style="width: 75px; -ms-touch-action: none;" aria-label="Share"><span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-share"></span><span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Share</span></div>`

Comment: Did you try ie.document.querySelector("[title='data visualization']").contentDocument.querySelector(".download").click by itself? No loop

Comment: I got an error : Run-Time error '424' Object Required

Comment: Even when stepping through slowly with F8?

Comment: Yes, tried to step thru the code but still the same, button not clicked.. I checked the element before the iframe, there's a `style="visibility: hidden`. do you think this might be the reason why I can't locate the element? btw, the site i'm automating is a Tableau Dashboard.

Comment: `<div class="tb-viz ng-isolate-scope" style="visibility: hidden; max-width: 1536px;" tb-test-id="viz" tb-window-max-width="tb-window-max-width" tb-visible="vizInitialized" on-viz-sized="onVizSized()" viz="viz">

<iframe title="data visualization" src="https://samplesite.com" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; visibility: visible;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the getElementsbyTagName method to get the Iframe first, then, according to the Iframe.contentDocument property to get the elements via the class Name.

Sample code as below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "<the website url>"

        While ie.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsbyClassName("tabToolbarButton tab-widget download")(0).Click
    End With
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

[Note] Please note the element's index when you are using the getElementsbyTagName and getElementsbyClassName. It is starting from 0.

Comment: Thanks! is there an easy way to get the index of an element? It's hard to navigate the HTML Document.

Comment: If the Iframe count is fixed, you could use F12 developer tools DOM Explorer to find the Iframe and get the index. The screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbQNU.png). Otherwise, you could try to add a different class name or id attribute for the iframes.